# How to run a command in .sh file during startup for Intel Edison?

Tags: command, startup, iot, intel-edison, startupscript

As there is no rc.local file in Intel Edison, how do I run a command in a .sh file during startup? I'm running **iwconfig wlan0 | grep -E -o ".{0,1}-.{0,6} |.{0,4}Mb/s.{0,3}|.{0,3}/70.{0,0}"** and want it to execute during every startup and save it into a text file.

Comment: Use systemd. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd_FAQ#How_can_I_make_a_script_start_during_the_boot_process.3F

Answer (score 0):

Intel Edison uses systemd for handling services. You can find these services in /lib/systemd/system , for e.g., create a copy of iotkit-agent.service, rename it to .service and modify accordingly.

Now all you have to do is

```
 systemctl daemon-reload
 systemctl start <yourscript>.service
```

To run this script on boot, you can enable it by running

```
systemctl enable <yourscript>.service
```

Now reboot and see if it runs the script. You can also check the status by running the command

```
systemctl status <yourscript>.service
```